# Message 'ToolsAPI not found' in a Form

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, toolsapi

In a package, I have a component which implements the ToolAPi *IOTAIDENotifier* Interface. The package can be setup, compiled and appears on the palette. A method of this component is designed to do something particular when a project, which uses it, is compiled (and not executed)...so far everything if OK.

The problem appears later, when I use this component on a TForm which belongs to another project.
When I try to build it, I get the compiler message **File not found: ToolsAPI.dcu**.

Here are the uses of the package:

```
Uses
  {$IFDEF PACKAGESETUP} DesignIntf, DesignEditors,{$ENDIF}
  Classes, ToolsAPI;
```

**PACKAGESETUP** is only defined when I compile the bpl

When I double click the error message, the IDE opens the file from which is declared the reference to ToolsAPI...How can I get rid of this problem ?

Comment: Are you trying to use ToolsAPI in a desktop app?

Comment: Yes. When I compile the desktop app, one of its component must do something specific in *BeforeCompile(...);* Actually the component is responsible for compiling a RES file used by the app...but obviously this is only used when the IDE is opened, not at the runtime.

Comment: Use of a compiled component for that sounds like last resort. A simple script, invoked from a pre-build event is how I would do this. Think also what happens when you do command line builds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ToolsAPI is only available in designtime packages. It exists to expose the IDE for customisation and so is available only under the IDE, i.e. in designtime packages. You will have to remove the reference to ToolsAPI from your desktop app.

Comment: Is there a directive which is defined when the IDE runs ? I think I could solve the problem by creating a sub component only if something like DESINGTIME is defined...

Comment: @az01, no. If there was, it would be too late, anyway; loading the design packages would have already been attempted before you could check. The proper way to do this is to separate your designtime code out into it's own package that uses `ToolsAPI` and the `Design*` stuff, and that designtime package requires your runtime package containing the rest of your code. You then use the designtime package in the IDE at designtime properly.

Comment: Hi! And what happens when you have a design-time package, and it can't find `ToolsAPI`?  (*kill me*)

Comment: @Ian not sure what you mean

Comment: Compiling a design-time only package `File not found: 'ToolsAPI.dcu'`. I.e. where `IOTAWizard` is defined.

Comment: Here I am, 11 years later, trying to find where `ToolsAPI.dcu` is.

Comment: @IanBoyd surely it's in one of the design time packages that you link to